# Flashback doesn't work after latest 12.04 Ubuntu update

Tags: 12.04, flash, ubuntu-bug

I have the latest 12.04 version of Ubuntu. Yesterday I installed the latest updates and right away I got this message:

'The following packages requested additional data downloads after package installation, but the data could not be downloaded or could not be processed.

flashplugin-installer

The download will be attempted again later, or you can try the download again now.  Running this command requires an active Internet connection.'

I then tried to install the plugin using the apt-get command and here are the results:

```
(.../flashplugin-installer_11.2.202.275ubuntu0.12.10.1_amd64.deb から) flashplugin-installer を展開しています...
update-notifier-common のトリガを処理しています ...
flashplugin-installer: downloading http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.275.orig.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 234, in process_download_requests
    dest_file = urllib.urlretrieve(files[i])[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 93, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 239, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 207, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 344, in open_http
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 958, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 818, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 780, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 761, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
flashplugin-installer (11.2.202.275ubuntu0.12.10.1) を設定しています
```

When I go to Youtube, there's a message in the right upper corner about installing the missing plugins. When I click on it, there's another message saying that Firefox is checking for the missing plugins but then nothing really happens. It is kind of weird since some flash videos on Youtube work and some do not.

What could be wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem yesterday. Maybe Ubuntu is having network troubles (also got some 403 errors on apt-get update for some time yesterday).

Today I just uninstalled the flashplayer-installer and installed it again. This time the network connection to archive.canonical.com worked fine. Just try it again some time later, this might solve the problem.

If you really need the flashplayer now, you could download it from http://get.adobe.com/de/flashplayer/ and install it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

The manual way is by doing the following:

(I'm assuming that you use Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10)

- download from Adobe the latest LINUX flash-player
- extract it in your downloadfolder (right click and select unpack)
- look in the extracted folder and see if **libflashplayer.so** is in it.
- Press ALT + F2 and type **gksudo nautilus**
- navigate to **usr/lib/mozilla/plugins**
- copy and paste the libflashplayer.so into that folder (plugins)
- close all windows and restart Firefox

That's it: you have manually installed the latest flashplayer without hastle.